# Ngrok Metasploit Msfvenom Android

Tags: android, ngrok, msfconsole

I'm sorry if this is too easy, but I'm starting to hack and I need help, please.

Here are some screenshots of my work so far...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPdJ5.jpg)

I'm using a real cellphone, not a virtual machine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4X7v.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTogq.png)

Please if someone would explain what is my mistake I would be so grateful!!!

I did not try much to be honest. Hope you can help me!